# Trying to show a random picture from Unsplash

Tags: reactjs, image, url

Hi this is my first React app im trying to build.
I'm trying to show a random image in React but i can't get
the image to show.

```html
import React from 'react';

function ImageList(props) {
    console.log(props);
   
    return (
    <div><img src={props} alt="cat"/></div>
    );
}
export default ImageList;
```

the props looks like this:
props: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568152950566-c1bf43f4ab28?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzNTkxNzd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NjE3NTY3NTc&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400"

When i inspect the img it says object Object.

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css'
import ImageList from './ImageList';


const App = () => {
    const [cats, setCats] = useState("");
 
   async function onSearchSubmit(term) {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/',{
    params: { query: term},
    headers:{
      Authorization: 'Client-ID //here i just where i put my key in '
    }

    });
  
setCats(response.data.urls.small);


}

return(
 <div className='App'>
<button onClick={() => {onSearchSubmit("cat")} }>
        Show a cat picture
      </button>
<ImageList props = {cats}/>
</div>
 
);}
export default App;
```

This is the rest of the code.

I am thankful for your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

props it's just the name of your prop.
Look at this row:

```
<ImageList props = {cats}/>
```

You shouldn't use the `props` name for your props. Use some meaningful name instead, like `cats`

```
<ImageList cats = {cats}/>

// And in ImageList
const ImageList = ({cats}) => {
  // do something with cats. Now it must be a string
}
OR
// props is an object
const ImageList = (props) => {
  const cats = props.cats
  // do something with cats. Now it must be a string
}
```